# Google Script for getting Some Values, and Some formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm working on a sheet that will get data transferred from one sheet to another. I've manipulated another script I've found and it's working pretty well. Until I need to get some cells as Values, and some as Formulas.

I need Col A-Col D as "getValues"
I need Col E-Col Q as "getFormulas"

Here's the formula that was working:

```
function Copy(){
  var origSheetObject = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Key1').getSheetByName('Daily Log');
  var destSheetObject = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Key2').getSheetByName('Imported Data');
  var origLastCol = origSheetObject.getLastColumn();
  var arrOrigData = origSheetObject.getRange (6, 1, 1, 17).getFormulas();       
  var destlastRow = destSheetObject.getLastRow()+1;
  var cont;
  for (cont = 0; cont <origLastCol; cont++)
    destSheetObject.getRange(destlastRow, 1+cont).setValue(arrOrigData[0][cont]);
```

I know If I were to change the getFormula to getValue I get just values and not the formulas I need to see. Here is what I've tried but it's not correct:

```
function Copy(){
  var origSheetObject = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Key1').getSheetByName('Daily Log');
  var destSheetObject = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Key2').getSheetByName('Imported Data');
  var origLastCol = origSheetObject.getLastColumn();
  var arrOrigData = origSheetObject.getRange (6, 1, 1, 4).getValues();
                    origSheetObject.getRange (6, 5, 1, 13).getFormulas();       
  var destlastRow = destSheetObject.getLastRow()+1;
  var cont;
  for (cont = 0; cont <origLastCol; cont++)
    destSheetObject.getRange(destlastRow, 1+cont).setValue(arrOrigData[0][cont]);
```

I'm not sure how to get it to let me pull values and formulas along the same row. Any suggestions would be awesome!

Comment: You should assign it to a variable in this way:   var arrOrigData = origSheetObject.getRange (6, 1, 1, 4).getValues();
  var arrorigformula = origSheetObject.getRange (6, 5, 1, 13).getFormulas();

Comment: I understand the process to assign that variable in that way, but how do I call for it to combine them in the destSheetObject as one line

Answer (score 0):

Get the values AND the formulas in different variables, then iterate trough the formula variable, if there is a formula, save that formula to the original variable, as such:

```
var arrOrigData = origSheetObject.getRange(1, 1, 1, 17).getValues();
var arrOrigForm = origSheetObject.getRange(1, 1, 1, 17).getFormulas();

for( lin in arrOrigForm )
  for( col in arrOrigForm[ lin ] )
    if( arrOrigForm[ lin ][ col ] != "" )
      arrOrigData [ lin ][ col ] = arrOrigForm[ lin ][ col ];
```

You can save this to a new function, as this

```
function getValuesAndFormulas( A1Range ){
  var arrOrigData = origSheetObject.getRange( A1Range ).getValues();
  var arrOrigForm = origSheetObject.getRange( A1Range ).getFormulas();

  for( lin in arrOrigForm )
    for( col in arrOrigForm[ lin ] )
      if( arrOrigForm[ lin ][ col ] != "" )
        arrOrigData [ lin ][ col ] = arrOrigForm[ lin ][ col ];

  return arrOrigData;
}
```

Only way to make it a oneLiner.

Comment: Kriggs, I really appreciate you helping me out. This type of stuff is out of my league. I'm just new to coding and trying to implement this change is driving me crazy! I tried to add your first set of suggested code and I'm getting an error "ReferenceError: "i" is not defined." Could you help me understand what I need to place in that area? I've included as a separate answer the code that I'm not trying to use based on your feedback.

Comment: Missed an `i` in the second `for`, it should be `arrOrigForm[ lin ]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Copy(){
   var origSheetObject = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Key1').getSheetByName('Daily Log');
   var destSheetObject = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Key2').getSheetByName('Imported Data');
   var origLastCol = origSheetObject.getLastColumn();
   var arrOrigData = origSheetObject.getRange(1, 1, 1, 17).getValues();
   var arrOrigForm = origSheetObject.getRange(1, 1, 1, 17).getFormulas();

   for( lin in arrOrigForm )
     for( col in arrOrigForm[ i ] )
       if( arrOrigForm[ lin ][ col ] != "" )
         arrOrigData [ lin ][ col ] = arrOrigForm[ lin ][ col ];      

   var destlastRow = destSheetObject.getLastRow()+1;
   var cont;
     for (cont = 0; cont <origLastCol; cont++)
         destSheetObject.getRange(destlastRow, 1+cont).setValue(arrOrigData[0][cont]);
 }
```

So thats what I've put goether based on your information. And I'm very open to realizing I'm not doing this right. If you could possibly edit this code and show me what it should look liked finished I should be able to work my way through my errors and learn what I'm not able to do right now. Thank you again for helping me with this.

Comment: You can update the initial question or comment the new code, but it's not practical to make a new question as an answer, you can delete it.